# Trace Program using gdb

Tags: c, linux, gdb

```
int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
  printf("%d");
  return 0;
}
```

I know this will print garbage, but how to trace the program using gdb to check garbage value?

Comment: There is no garbage value in your code. There would be if you called `printf("%d\n", x);` with an uninitialized `int x;`. And if you pass `-Wall` to `gcc` at compile time you get a warning. So I don't understand the question (and you could put a breakpoint in `printf` with `gdb`)

Comment: Do you want to know what the "garbage value" is _before_ calling `printf`? Or do you want to be able to _step into_ the `printf` function?

Comment: I agree with the others that your question is not entirely clear. What exactly are you trying to get by using `gdb` that you wouldn't be able to just by running the program?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch There's no garbage value in the code directly, but the `printf` call will happily read a value of the "stack" even when no argument is present, and print that.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I do know that, but the original poster perhaps don't. Actually, I don't understand the question (and believe the original poster don't understand it neither)

Comment: Why are you asking? I don't think that you are writing and compiling your example code (and `gcc -Wall` would have caught the mistake)

Answer (score 3):

You might put a breakpoint on `printf` and inspect the stack using `$esp`

`gdb` does not know about garbage values; but `printf` in your case happens to retrieve (using `va_args`) some "undefined" (actually "uninitialized", i.e. containing some previous garbage) value from the stack.

Comment: I want to step into printf. I was reading C and in one interview question and I found this question, I immediately understand that this will print garbage, but I want to debug using gdb to know the background process of C program.